# Compile-time error with TurboC++

Tags: c++

I am compiling with an old software TurboC++ 4.5(1995) and I am having some errors. Can anyone help?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<math.h>

void cal_root(int,int,int,float&,float&);
void main()
{
  float root1=0,root2=0;
  int a,b,c;
  cout<<"Enter the three co-efficients of quadratic equation with spaces.\n";
  cin>>a>>b>>c;
  cal_root(a,b,c,root1,root2);
  cout<<"The roots for given Quadratic Equation are "<<root1<<" & "<<root2<<".";
}
void cal_root(int a,int b,int c,float& root1,float& root2)
{
  root1=-b+(sqrt((b*b)-4ac))/(2a); //error here
  root2=-b-(sqrt((b*b)-4ac))/(2a); //error here
}
```

I'm getting the following error:
   `Function call missing ) in function cal_root(int, int, int, float&, float &)`
at lines 16 and 17

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using *such* an old compiler? You are only going to cause pain for yourself unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: i know its crap but in my school they teach with this...

Comment: If you are studying computer science, ditch that school if you ever want to use C++ professionally... I'm serious... That code would not compile at all even after fixing for the errors in `cal_root`.

Comment: i am not only studying CS but other Science subject also, its kinda basic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not in a math class, you have to write out multiplications explicitly:

```
4ac -> 4*a*c
2a -> 2*a
```

Comment: Don't forget to put `2*a` into parens, e.g. `(2*a)`, or you're risking `/2*a` to become `divide by 2, then multiply by a`. Alternatively you could just repeatedly divide by both: `/2/a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do multiplication like this:

```
4ac
2a
```

You have to spell it out:

```
4 * a * c
2 * a
```

But make sure you are liberal with your parenthesis, because, for example, `2 * a` in that expression will first divide by 2, then multiply by a.  When in fact, you want to divide by 2 and divide by a.

In fact, your -b is also badly placed, due to order of operations.  The expression should look like this:

```
(-b + sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c)))
    / (2*a)
```

Comment: You get the +1 as you are the first to mention prenthsis. $5 says somone who tries 2a would also try `...)) / 2 * a`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave operators as you would in algebra. `4ac` and `2a` should be `4*a*c` and `2*a`.

Also, get a better compiler / IDE. Turbo C++ was the worst piece of crap when I started programming about 10 years ago. It's still that bad. Use Netbeans for example.

The simple fact that it allows for `void main()` proves my point. Main should never be declared `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply variables by constants via `2x` and the like, as it gets treated as a literal, 2, with a suffix of x, or whatever your variable happens to be, suffixes changing the representation of the variable (e.g. LL would treat it as a long long).

Instead, use `operator*`:

```
4 * a * c
2 * a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write 4ac or 2a - this is not maths.

Change

```
4ac = 4*a*c
2a = 2*a
```

Also void main is [wrong](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html).

Comment: @user142187 What is wrong or right does not depend on the compiler. Click on 'wrong' in my answer.

Comment: @user142187 Because the complier allows it does not mean it is correct. It violates the c++ spec and you are just lucky that you have yet to write anything that would break because of it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the compiler is older than the spec.

Comment: the compiler is older than the spec,,.,yeah

Comment: *"What is wrong or right does not depend on the compiler."* -- It most certainly does.  Assuming the goal is to produce a working program, then the behavior of the compiler is far more important than what the language standard says.

Comment: OP does not seem to care much about C++ so Benjamin might be right. If OP does not write code that will be shared with others outside his class and that his class teaches this horrendous non-standard C++ then I guess he could care less that this is not proper C++ in according to the standard or to most compilers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
  void cal_root(int a,int b,int c,float& root1,float& root2)
  {
      root1=-b+(sqrt((b*b)-4ac))/(2a); //error here
      root2=-b-(sqrt((b*b)-4ac))/(2a); //error here
  }
```

this should be written as

```
    void cal_root(int a,int b,int c,float& root1,float& root2)
    {
      root1=-b+(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a); //correction
      root2=-b-(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a); //correction
    }
```

secondly avoid using void in main...(just a suggestion)